# Separate Routes file and Models with fastify-mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, fastify

I am new to the Fastify Ecosystem, and I have been using the official `fastify-mongodb` plugin for connecting to MongoDB. I have had previous experience with Express+Mongoose, but `fastify-mongodb` does things quite differently.

I wanted to have a different `routes.js` file containing all the routes, but I cannot figure out how to connect to the db.

This works, if I put it on `server.js` :

```
const Fastify = require('fastify');
const server = Fastify({
    logger: true
});
server.register(require('fastify-mongodb'), {
    forceClose: true,
    url: process.env.MONGO_URL
})
server.get('/test', function (req, reply) {
    const db = this.mongo.db
    reply.send(db)
})
```

But, if I use a separate route and do something like:

`routes.js`:

```
const routes = async (server, options) => {
    server.register(require('fastify-mongodb'), {
        forceClose: true,
        url: process.env.MONGO_URL
    })
server.get('/test', function (req, reply) {
    const db = this.mongo.db
    reply.send(db)
})
...
```

And then on `server.js`:

```
server.register(require('./routes'))
```

it simply doesn't work. `this.mongo` becomes undefined.

Also, I cannot figure out the equivalent of `mongoose.Schema` in `fastify-mongodb`.

What exactly am I doing wrong? Is there any way to achieve Mongoose-style schema and modularity with Fastify-MongoDB?

Comment: I think you are doing it right, which version of fastify are you using?

Comment: Fastify 2.14.1.

Comment: your example works to me

Comment: Can you dump your working code on GitHub/GitLab?

Comment: I think I've found your issue

Answer (score -2):

The `fastify.mongo.db` is set only if you define a Mongo connection URL with the database name like `mongodb://localhost:27017/my-database`.

If you set the URL to `mongodb://localhost:27017` you must select the database first:

```
const db = this.mongo.client.db('my-database')
```

Your code works with this URL fix:

```js
const fastify = require('fastify')
const server = fastify({ logger: true })
server.register(require('./routes'))
server.listen(3000)
```

Routes:

```js
const routes = async (server, options) => {
  server.register(require('fastify-mongodb'), {
    forceClose: true,
    url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/my-database'
  })

  server.get('/test', function (req, reply) {
    const db = this.mongo.db
    console.log(db)
    reply.send({ db: !!db })
  })
}

module.exports = routes
```

Comment: I am using an url, pointing to a DB. Like I said, it works when the routes are put directly in the server.js but fails whenever it is refactored into a routes.js file.

Comment: Could you try my snippet? What is the output?

Comment: I have encountered the same problem. Have you got solution for it?

Comment: The script works, the issue is how the files are loaded so the question should be updated to tell you why your script doesn't work. Would you mind to drop a github repo that replicate your issue?